# Limit wp_nav_menu_objects() only to first-level menu items

Tags: menus, urls, limit

I need to alter my menu URLs and add "/" to the beginning on every page except homepage. It works well using this piece of code:

```
function change_menu($items){

    if(!is_front_page()){
        foreach($items as $item){
            $item->url = "/" .  $item->url;
        }
    }

    return $items;
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'change_menu');
```

However, I also need to limit it to only first-level items (all the items in the sub-menu should remain the same). I know there is 'depth' argument available, but I have no clue how to use it.

**UPDATE:** My intention was to filter anchor links from classic ones. I have a microsite, which uses menu items as an anchor links. One of them has a submenu with links to custom subpages. Adding a slash at the beginning of all menu links on every subpage pointed the anchors to homepage (which works well), however it messed up the classic links.

I managed to write a workaround:

```
// if the URL is an anchor, add a slash   
if (strpos($item->url, '#!/') !== false) {
    $item->url = "/" .  $item->url;
}
```

However I would like to hear some ideas, if it can be done in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

`depth` argument, available in functions attached to `wp_nav_menu_objects` hook, refers to the max depth of rendered menu (how many menu levels will be visible on site).

To change only first-level elements, you can check in the loop if the menu item has a parent.

```
function change_menu($items) {

    if( !is_front_page() ) {
        foreach($items as $item) {
            if ( $item->menu_item_parent != 0 )
                continue;
            $item->url = "/" .  $item->url;
        }
    }
    return $items;
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'change_menu');
```